# Does any motherborad and CPU fit in normal cabinets

Tags: cpu, motherboard, case

I have this [Computer case](http://www.legitreviews.com/thermaltake-armor-mx-midtower-atx-computer-case_738)

It had

1. Core 2 Quad Q600 processor
2. Intel [MB 975xbx2 motherboard](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/15065/eng/D975XBX2_ProductGuide05_English.pdf)

As that MB has only 8gb Max RAM so i thought i need to replace the MB and processor to get more RAM. so i have got this

1. [Gigabyte Motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4714#sp)
2. [AMD CPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819113280)

Now before opening my old computer and to fit the new one. i want to ask

1. Can that motherboard and CPU fit in my new case
2. My old MB has FAN installed on the top of CPU. do i need to get new FAN or i don't need fan at all or MB comes with it
3. DO i need anything else to make it work or just `MB, CPU and ddr3RAM` are the things i need to make it work

Also i have 500w power supply. Are all PS work on all motherboards or may need different one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, your motherboard will fit in the case.  Both your case and the motherboard are [ATX form factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX).  ATX is a standard that most motherboard and cases use, so they are all interchangeable.
2. Your CPU comes with a fan and heat sink in the box.  Just a FYI, the old one would not fit the new CPU.  Heat sinks and fans are designed to fit specific size and shape of CPUs and sockets.
3. You have everything you need to make it work.  The motherboard has onboard graphics, so you do not need a graphics card.

AS for your power supply, without knowing the model its impossible to say if it will work or not.  It *may* have the right power connectors.  If not, you would have to purchase one that does.